# What is meant by "code that runs out of the sandbox" for SIP in Mac OS X?

Tags: terminology

I know what it means for code to run in a sandboxed environment, where it can only access a limited set of resources or only have access to virtualized resources.

However, the following sentence in Apple's documentation intrigues me: `"...code that runs out of the sandbox."`.

Does that mean code that don't run in a sandbox ("out") or code that runs in a sandbox?

> What is System Integrity Protection? According to Apple’s
>   documentation:
>
> A new security policy that applies to every running process, including privileged code and code that runs out of the sandbox. The policy extends additional protections to components on disk and at run-time, only allowing system binaries to be modified by the system installer and software updates. Code injection and runtime attachments to system binaries are no longer permitted.

https://chrisshort.net/disabling-mac-os-x-el-capitan-system-integrity-protection/